ScreenCaptureKit capture image with multiple displays
I have a macOS app that uses screen capture logic. It was originally coded using the Quartz CG API:
if let cgimage = CGDisplayCreateImage(CGMainDisplayID(), rect: cgRect) {...}

and this worked as expected even when capturing a screen rect that began on secondary monitor and ended on primary monitor (or was entirely contained on secondary monitor).
However now that API is deprecated and you're supposed to use ScreenCaptureKit instead.
So I have attempted to convert the code. The trial code is:
let scConfig = SCStreamConfiguration()
scConfig.sourceRect = drect
scConfig.width = Int(drect.width)
scConfig.height = Int(drect.height)
SCScreenshotManager.captureImage(contentFilter: sFilter, configuration: scConfig) {any,error in
       if let cgim = any {
           print("image dims \(cgim.width), \(cgim.height), requested: \(drect)")
                self.writeToFile2(cgim)
                ... //process the image
            }
            else {
                print("SCREEN CAP failed")
            }
        }
     ...

where sFilter was previously set based on main screen display (with no exclusions). This code also "works" as long as the capture rect is entirely on primary monitor. But it fails if the rect spans both monitors or is fully contained on secondary monitor. By "fails" I mean it produces empty image for the portion of the rect on secondary monitor.
So my question is: How to use ScreenCaptureKit to obtain screen shot of rectangle that spans dual monitors?

Does it work if you capture using a separate rectangle for each screen?

thanks for the reply. I had tried this by adding some additional trial logic to generate an array of rectangles defined as the intersection of the requested rectangle and the display screen frame (for each display screen in the shared content); then creating image for each (non-empty) rectangle in this array filtered to its appropriate display screen; then combining these images back into 1 image. This approach does work; however it really seems like a ridiculous amount of processing to accomplish what was previously done with 1 line of code.
